# How to create chef tag using ridley

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm using ruby ridley plugin to bootstrap the node and install some packages. However, I'm trying to create a chef tag using the ridley plugin but I'm unable to find any resources online.

is there a way to create chef tag using ridley or any other best way to do this from ruby?

Comment: Given that Google turns up nothing relevant for “chef tag ridley” (literally this question shows up), I suspect you need to clarify using the correct terms for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Node tags aren't a specific object, they are just a convention around node attributes. Specifically it's an array called `tags` at the normal level. You can set this via any API tool that can get/set node objects. Unless you need high concurrency I would probably recommend using the chef-api gem instead of Ridley, it's simpler for management script use cases.